# Why do I need reputation to vote?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

Why do I need reputation to vote? I understand the necessity of keeping the site as helpful, and clean, as possible, but why can I not up-vote the correct answer to the questions I have asked?

Also, I have seen a few questions I would be able to help with, but am currently unable to because of reputation point restrictions.

Comment: To stop people from building sockpuppets

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: This goes back to the original founders' ideas. They want to reel in trolling and drive-by misbehavior. Plus it helps to make it more gamified

Comment: Rep thresholds are for two reasons: 1. Reducing misuse. 2. Reducing abuse.

Comment: And "sockpuppets" are accounts created primarily for voting fraud.

Comment: @ryanyuyu - thanks for clarifying `sockpuppets` - i didn't realy get what they were

Comment: @Coffee: Never heard of "reeling in" anything you don't want. Did you mean "rein in"?

Comment: Reel in. Fishing reference

Comment: @Coffee the logic is that basically, with no restriction for upvoting, I could create a post, then use a script to throw up 10+ new accounts and just upvote my post. Obviously this will be caught by some script or other, and then handled by mods. But if you can simply stop these before voting fraud, isn't it better? :)

Comment: *I have seen a few questions I would be able to help with* - are you talking about answers or just making comments?

Comment: Making sure you know that votes have to be earned

Answer (score 7):

> Why do I need reputation to vote?

Basic reputation is required to vote otherwise voting fraud would be much easier to perform and get away with. Some fraud accounts will be created and without contributing to site, they can be directly used to upvote some specific user's questions & answers. Means protecting sock-puppets accounts, lower down the voting frauds.

> I have seen a few questions I would be able to help with, but am
>   currently unable to because of reputation point restrictions.

If you see some questions where you think you can help, then you can directly help them with answers/comments. There is no restriction to add answer based on reputation. From day 1 since you join SO, you can add an answer. As per [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

**Basic use of the site, including asking questions, answering, and
suggesting edits, does not require any reputation at all.**